# Binding ng-options with a default value that is dynamic from the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select, ng-options

I have multiple AngularJS select drop-down which can be set to a boolean value.

The initial data is driven from the server and I want to set the selected value of the drop down to the server value.

At the moment I get three options to select when the selected option should be the one from the server.

I have set up a Plunker here:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/bdiX5AA7jtgSLaP6

Which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I don't see the `?` as an option, only `true` or `false` : https://next.plnkr.co/edit/fs9q5sAtNL3saKNQ

Comment: My bad.  I meant that the selected option is blank.  It's value when inspected in dev tools is `?`

Comment: Are you using the same values in `$scope.list` as in the plunker? Because in the plunker `isMultiply` never has blank or ? or anything else than true or false. See my link, when you click the CLICK label, it shows you the values in an alert. Always a boolean.

Comment: When I view in Chrome i see the first selected option as empty or blank then true and false.  The default selected option in the drop down should be the boolean value of the `isMultiply` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it.

The drop downs were showing empty on load because of your `track by` in `ng-options`. 
Not sure why you had that but it's what broke it:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/fs9q5sAtNL3saKNQ